Maps between topological manifolds of the same dimension property
Assume $M_1,M_2$ are two connected compact topological manifolds of the same dimension $n$. Assume $f:M_1\rightarrow M_2$ and $g:M_2\rightarrow M_1$ are two maps such that on homology groups, we have $(g\circ f)_{*}:H_n(M_1)\rightarrow H_n(M_1)$ is the identity.
Does this imply that $f$ is surjective?
If $M_1,M_2$ are smooth manifolds and the maps $f,g$ are smooth, then since $M_1,M_2$ are compact, both $f$ and $g$ are proper. I think the above implies that $\int f^{*}\omega\neq 0$ for some $\omega$ which means it is enough to show $deg(f)\neq 0$.
How to see this for topological manifolds? I think one needs to break it into cases, orientable and non orientable.

Assuming that $M_1, M_2$ are still orientable, yes. You can prove the contrapositive: if $f$ is not surjective then it factors through $M_2$ minus a point. Now try to show that $H_n$ of this thing is zero.

@QiaochuYuan What if $M_i$ are not orientable?

@monoidaltransform Then $H_n(M_i) = 0$ and the condition is vacuous.

...although you could ask about $\mathbb{F}_2$-coefficients in that case, and then what Qiaochu Yuan said still works.

@monoidaltransform How do you know $H_n(M) \cong H_n(M - p) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

@BenSteffan I wrote proof for $M_i$ orientable

@monoidaltransform Apart from a small issue ("Since $M_2$ is a connected but not compact $n$-manifold" you obviously mean $M_2 - p$ here) this looks good to me. I'd suggest that you post this as a proper answer, perhaps incorporating what has been said about the non-orientable case. :)

Thanks to @Ben Steffan and @Qiaochu Yuan, my solution is as follows:
If $M_i$ is non-orientable for $i=1,2$ then hypothesis is vacuously true.
Assume $M_1$ and $M_2$ are orientable. The assumptions imply $f_{*}$ is injective. If $f$ is not surjective, then $f=i\circ h:M_1\rightarrow (M_2-p)\rightarrow M_2$, where first map $h$ is restriction of codomain of $f$ and $i$ is inlcusion. So. $f_{*}=i_{*}\circ h_{*}$. Since $M_2-p$ is connected but not compact $n$-manifold, $H_n(M_2-p)=0$. So, $f_{*}=0$, but $f_{*}$ is injective which cannot be.

In the non-orientable case, the hypothesis is vacuously true, but the conclusion need not hold.
